# How to use "*" to make letters using rows and columns

Tags: c++

Here is the code of which I'm writing to create the letter "Z" for example just cant figure out how to connect the rows and columns. Also don't know why its re-writing the code as many times by the user input. ex: user inputs 5 rows, it produces the "letter" 5 times over. if anyone is able to help me resolve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <random>
 #include <time.h>
 using namespace std; //when compiler sees a name it does not recognize, assume std; 
 
 //Program 2 by anon
 
 
int main() {
  cout<<"This program draws characters. Select character, then height(s)\n";
  const string PROMPT{"how many rows tall? (0 to quit): "};

  bool running{true};
  while (running) {
    cout << "\nOption: a)Z b)H /)/ \\)\\ q)quit? (q to quit): ";
    char option{}; cin>>option;

    if (option=='a') { // box
      while (true) {
      
        cout << "([z]) " << PROMPT;
        int rows=0;
        cin >> rows;
        if (rows<=0) break;
        for (int col{1}; col<=rows; ++col) { // for each column
            for (int row{1}; row<=rows; ++row) 
            cout << string(rows-row, ' ') << "*\n";
            cout << "*"; 
        }
        cout<<endl;
      }
    }

  if (option=='b') { // forward slash
      while (true) {
        cout << "(H) " << PROMPT;
        int rows=0;
        cin >> rows;
        if (rows<=0) break;
        for (int row{1}; row<=rows; ++row) {
          cout << string(row-row, ' ') << "*\n";
        for (int col{1}; col<=rows; ++col);
        }
        cout<<endl;
      }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    if (option=='/') { // forward slash
      while (true) {
        cout << "(/) " << PROMPT;
        int rows=0;
        cin >> rows;
        if (rows<=0) break;
        for (int row{1}; row<=rows; ++row) {
          cout << string(rows-row, ' ') << "*\n";
        }
        cout<<endl;
      }
    }

    else if (option=='\\') { // back slash
      while (true) {
        cout << "(\\) " << PROMPT;
        int rows=0;
        cin >> rows;
        if (rows<=0) break;
        for (int row{1}; row<=rows; ++row) { // backslash
          cout << string(row-1, ' ') << "*\n";
        }
        cout<<endl;
      }
    }

    else if (option=='q') {
      break;
    }

    else {
      cout<<"  Invalid option, try again.\n";
    }
  }

  cout<<"Goodbye\n";
  return 0;
}



desired output:

a) Z b) H /)/ \\)\\ q) quit:a

How many rows tall? (0 to quit): 8

********
       *
      *
     *
    *
   *
  *
 *
*
********
how many rows tall? (0 to quit): // loop reruns.
```

Comment: step through with a debugger. I mean it loops n times because thats what you tell it to do. HArd to make suggestion since its not clear what you are exactly after. Mybe if you showed what output (edit the question, not a comment) you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to draw the Z you need to add the horizontal "*" line at the beginning and the end. In addition you have to remove the outer loop, to avoid the letter to be drawn multiple times. This loop needs to be seperate at the beginning and the end, to draw the horizontal line:

```
    if (option == 'a') 
    { // box
        while (true) 
        {
            cout << "([z]) " << PROMPT;

            int rows = 0;
            cin >> rows;

            if (rows <= 0) break;

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) 
                cout << "*";
            cout << endl;

            for (int row{ 1 }; row <= rows; ++row)
                cout << string(rows - row, ' ') << "*\n";

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                cout << "*";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```